# Кнопка с выпадающим меню

Tags: jquery, javascript

Привет, у меня такая проблема: есть кнопка, при нажатие на которую открывается и закрывается выпадающее меню. Если курсор уходит из поля кнопки или меню более чем на 0.7 сек, оно само закрывается.

Всё это работает, но с одним недостатком: если меню открыть кнопкои 2 раза подряд, то оно закрывается, даже при возврате курсора в поле меню или кнопки. Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможные решения, заранее благодарю.

Вот код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

<style>
.tblock {
    float: left;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
ul { 
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.2;
    list-style: none outside none;
}
#dt {
    border:1px solid #444;
    padding:4px;
    position:absolute;
    top:190px;
    left:200px;
}
#sort_link {
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position: relative;
}

ul#sort_list{min-width:145px;padding:11px 10px 0;top:32px;}
ul#sort_list li:last-child{margin-bottom:8px;}
a#sort_link{border:1px solid #eee;border-radius:3px;padding: 3px 15px; position:relative;}
#sort_link:hover{border:1px solid #cccccc;border-radius:3px;padding: 3px 15px;position:relative;}
#sort_link span{border-color:transparent;border-top:4px solid #ccc;display:none;border-style:solid;border-width:4px;height:0;position:absolute;right:5px;top:8px;width:0;}
#sort_link:hover span{display:block;}
#sort_list a{font-size:1em;}

#sort_list { 
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px #C2C1C1;
    display: none;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
</style>

<script>
$(function() {
idleTimer = null;
idleState = false; // состояние отсутствия
idleWait = 700; // время ожидания в мс. (1/1000 секунды)

    $('#sort_link').click(function() {
    $('#sort_list').slideToggle('slow');

$('#sort_list, #sort_link').mousemove(function() { // мышь над кнопкой
$('#dt').css("background","orange"); // детектор
clearTimeout(idleTimer); // отменяем прежний временной отрезок
if(idleState == true){
}
// Действия на возвращение пользователя.
});

$('#sort_list, #sort_link').mouseout(function(){ // мышь ушла с кнопки
$('#dt').css("background","green"); // детектор

idleState = false;
idleTimer = setTimeout(function(){ 
// Действия на отсутствие пользователя
$('#sort_list').css("display", "none");
$('#dt').css("background","red"); // детектор
$('#sort_link, #sort_list').unbind('mousemove mouseout');
idleState = true;

}, idleWait);

    });
    });
});
</script>

</head><body>

<div class="tblock">
    <a href="#" id="sort_link">сортировать:</a>

    <ul id="sort_list">
        <li><a href="javascript://">По Дате</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript://">По Названию</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript://">По Рейтингу</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript://">По Переходам</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="dt">detector</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

может так:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
.tblock {
    float: left;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
ul { 
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.2;
    list-style: none outside none;
}
#dt {
    border:1px solid #444;
    padding:4px;
    position:absolute;
    top:190px;
    left:200px;
}
#sort_link {
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position: relative;
}

ul#sort_list{min-width:145px;padding:11px 10px 0;top:32px;}
ul#sort_list li:last-child{margin-bottom:8px;}
a#sort_link{border:1px solid #eee;border-radius:3px;padding: 3px 15px; position:relative;}
#sort_link:hover{border:1px solid #cccccc;border-radius:3px;padding: 3px 15px;position:relative;}
#sort_link span{border-color:transparent;border-top:4px solid #ccc;display:none;border-style:solid;border-width:4px;height:0;position:absolute;right:5px;top:8px;width:0;}
#sort_link:hover span{display:block;}
#sort_list a{font-size:1em;}

#sort_list { 
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px #C2C1C1;
    display: none;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
</style>

<script>
$(function() {
idleTimer = null;
idleState = false; // состояние отсутствия
idleWait = 700; // время ожидания в мс. (1/1000 секунды)

var _flag = true;

    $('#sort_link').click(function() {

    if (_flag){
    _flag = false;
    $('#sort_list').slideToggle('slow');

$('#sort_list, #sort_link').mousemove(function() { // мышь над кнопкой
$('#dt').css("background","orange"); // детектор
clearTimeout(idleTimer); // отменяем прежний временной отрезок
if(idleState == true){
}
// Действия на возвращение пользователя.
});

$('#sort_list, #sort_link').mouseout(function(){ // мышь ушла с кнопки
$('#dt').css("background","green"); // детектор

idleState = false;
idleTimer = setTimeout(function(){

// Действия на отсутствие пользователя
$('#sort_list').css("display", "none");
$('#dt').css("background","red"); // детектор
$('#sort_link, #sort_list').unbind('mousemove mouseout');
idleState = true;

_flag = true; }, idleWait);

            });
        }
    });

});
</script>

</head><body>
<div class="tblock"> <a href="#" id="sort_link">сортировать:</a>

<ul id="sort_list">
    <li><a href="javascript://">По Дате</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript://">По Названию</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript://">По Рейтингу</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript://">По Переходам</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="dt">detector</div>

</body> </html>
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример, но ведь тогда меню нельзя сворачивать кнопкой ?.
Я новичок в jquery и возможно мой вариант не самый удачный это я к тому что возможно это можно реализовать и по другому главное оставить идею, меню сворачивается и разворачивается кнопкой и ичезает, но не сразу а при уходе курсора с элементов меню или кнопки.

Comment: Немного переделал ваш ответ с флагом и все стало, как надо. Ещё раз спасибо вам. Переставил if (flag) - ниже в коде.

`// Действия на возвращение пользователя.
// });
//     if (flag){
//     flag = false;`